# recenter-top-bottom overridden in eshell

Tags: emacs, eshell

I am using emacs 24.3

One strange thing I noticed about emacs shell (eshell) when recentered(using C-l), goes to bottom after any command is executed.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps customizing either or both of the following variables could assist to control the behavior you are experiencing:  `eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-output` and `eshell-scroll-show-maximum-output`?  The default value of the variable `eshell-output-filter-functions` includes the function `eshell-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom`, and perhaps that function is causing the behavior you experience?

Comment: This is exactly what you want. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28828/794